Why didn't Walter White choose to work at Gray Matter instead of becoming a drug lord in Breaking Bad?
In "Breaking Bad", we see that Walter White, a brilliant chemist, chooses to enter the dangerous world of methamphetamine production rather than accept a job offer from his former colleagues at Gray Matter Technologies.
Given Walter's high intelligence and the obvious benefits of working at a successful pharmaceutical company, why didn't he make this seemingly more logical decision?
It's a superior choice for the following reasons;

Gray Matter could have provided a high salary and potentially covered his medical expenses.
It would have been a legal and much safer option for supporting his family.
The job would have utilized his chemistry expertise in a legitimate field. Chemistry was also his passion.
It is far more respectable than being a drug lord

What factors in Walter's character or backstory explain this seemingly irrational choice?
I'm looking for answers that delve into Walter's psychology, and any relevant details from the series that shed light on this decision.

It is simple, Pride... the show clearly shows him as a stubborn prideful person who doesn't accept help and thinks he is better than everybody else. Even as a druglord he acts like he has the moral highground over other criminals.

Related and to some degree even a duplicate: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/38980/why-did-walt-have-to-teach-high-school-chemistry/

It is far more respectable than being a drug lord => a lowly corporate employee is arguably not all that respected...

@JonathanReez Any lowly corporate job is more respectable than a criminal job that harms society. I don't think any criminal who gets caught and serving jail time will disagree with that. Even if he doesn't get caught, think of the stress from worrying about being caught. Look at Walter and what he subjected his family to.

Walter died a happy man, having left $9 million to his family, humiliated Gretchen and Elliott, set his best friend free, and forever remembered as a dangerous criminal mastermind. I don't think dying in a hospice with barely any money for his family was his preferred way to go...

Early in the story we learn from Walter's teaching in the chemistry class that he clearly had developed a disdain for working for companies. The anecdote of patent for synthetically produced diamonds shines rather brightly to illuminate his position. The worker was awarded a 10 US dollars saving bond for having discovered how to make diamonds and the company went ahead to make billions...

@JonathanReez - funny, I felt like that about Walter White, but I felt no such understanding about Tony Soprano. He was just a vicious murderer. I know it is unclear whether he dies in the finale.

The timing of Walt's history matters here. He broke with Grey Matter a long time ago.
Walter White broke with Grey Matter a long time before the events depicted in the show. He could have joined at the firm's startup and his ideas were significant in the firm's success. This is significant.
The rich owners–his former colleagues–offer to pay for his treatment, as well as making a vague job offer (where the health insurance would pay for his treatment) though it is far from clear what his role would be. But both offers seem to be made out of charity not a belief that White has a big contribution to make based on his capability.
When White rebuffs their offer of money he never makes the reason why explicit (though he already knows he can make enough from drug dealing). His motivations for rejecting their help are not stated explicitly but seem clear from many of his other actions and this is where his long-ago history with Grey Matter matters.
He seems to hold some grudge against the firm because they have been successful partly by exploiting his ideas. But he broke with them long ago for opaque reasons (but possibly because he fell out with his ex-girlfriend for some reason). Whatever the inciting incident, he clearly resents their success. His ego seems to assume he deserved to share in that success (even though his own, possibly precipitate, actions led to his split from them). And many of his actions demonstrate clearly that his need to prove himself is a major driving force in all his actions. His bruised ego (he is a badly paid teacher not a rich entrepreneur) needs to prove he could achieve great success by his own actions. Which he does, albeit in the drug business. But success is success as far as his ego in concerned: he has proved his underlying capability to himself.
Given his ego-driven need to prove himself, it seems clear that he rejects what is, in effect, charity offered by Grey Matter. If he accepts the offer of money, he is admitting he cannot achieve success by his own actions. And his ego simply cannot accept that. He knows he can be successful in empire building and money making by using his skills in the drug trade. Moral issues don't even come into play.

Your answer is great, apart from the fact that they do suggest he comes back to Grey Matter. From the script:  "Are you asking me to come work for you at Gray Matter?", "Yeah, why not? You'd fit right in."

It isn't until Eliot says "We have excellent health insurance." that Walter twigs why they are offering him a job again.  Its not for his brilliance, its because of charity.

@iandotkelly that seems like a potential answer.

No, I feel like this has most of the points I would make, just remove that one point.  Its still true that their offer is about the treatment and that he still holds a grudge.

I think there is important context that the business owner, Schwartz, isn't just a former colleague. He and White were partners that started Grey Matter. White and Black (Schwartz in German) make grey. Walter's name is in the business. And they succeeded without him. And then Schwartz married the woman he loved. Walter's resentment runs deep.

@iandotkelly I've corrected the part about the job offer as your memory is better than mine.

For what it's worth, Vince Gilligan confirmed later what the show hinted at about why Walt and Gretchen broke up: he didn't know how rich Gretchen was until he met her family, and when he found out it made him feel inferior and he bolted, and framed it in his mind as purposeful. That was the event they danced around describing in the season 2 meeting between the two of them. It also ties into Walter's pride here, so it might be worth mentioning? The interview where this came up is quoted here: https://www.huffpost.com/entry/vince-gilligan-walter-white-gray-matter_n_56e85f27e4b0b25c91838d57

I've always thought that part of the genius of Breaking Bad was the gradually sketched in details that filled out psychology and motivations. They mystery of his resignation from Gray Matter, leading to the question of why an extremely talented Ph.D. chemist is working as a high school teacher even though he apparently hates it. Eventually we learn that he not only stormed out of Gray Matter in a huff, but that he also stormed out of a job at Sandia Laboratories for unclear reasons. Walter White apparently is a difficult man who has a pathological need to be THE boss.

There are some good answers here already that I agree with, but neither of them mention the depth of Walt's ego and how that plays out later. Minor spoilers if you're just watching the show for the first time.
Walt first rejects Grey Matter's (Gretchen and Elliott) offer because he senses they're pitying him, and his recent cancer diagnosis puts his ego into overdrive. While he is shown at the beginning of the show tolerating a lot of abuse (from his students at his car wash job, from his boss, dead end high school job when his talents are so much more) after diagnosis he's shown standing up for himself (shorting the battery of the guy at the gas station mocking his son, quitting his job at the car wash). The rejection of Grey Matter's medical is an extension of this standing-up-for-himself: he doesn't know how much time he has left, but he wants to finally do what's important for him, and that's independence at first.
There are some flashbacks to the falling-out he had with Gretchen and Elliott and he resents their success. But once he makes some money making and selling drugs and paying for his own treatment, he does use Grey Matter money as a cover story to explain to Skyler why he's getting treatment. This eventually blows up as Skyler gets suspicious and talks to Gretchen trying to smooth things over and Gretchen admits she hasn't been giving money to Walt; Skyler has a breakdown over this and eventually forces Walt to tell the truth.
Further support for the "Walt's ego" reason: even Walt's opportunity to suggest the illicit drug money is coming from the charity his son set up doesn't sit right with him, he can't "take it lying down" he has to flex and let the people he loves know that he's earning it somehow, even though that raises suspicion with his DEA brother-in-law. A lot of the conflict in the middle seasons of the show come from the easy opportunities to claim income from a legitimate source and Walt refusing to accept them.
Indeed, you could say the whole show revolves around what could have been an easy path for Walt; don't get treatment, or accept aid in treatment... his choices and consequences create all the dynamic tension and drama in the show. There's an old comic that comes to mind that boils the whole show down to a few frames, if health care weren't out-of-control expensive in the U.S.:


This comic is so spot on, and makes me feel sad for US people. Then, why don't they just change it? They are still a democracy I suppose?

One important note: Walt's primary motivation in Season 1 was to leave money for his family, not to pay for his cancer treatment. Remember that he came up with the $737k number by starting out from how much money is needed to pay out his mortgage and pay for college for his kids. If he lived in the UK he'd get free treatment from the NHS but his family would still be left in a bind after his passing.

@hitchhiker its already been changed since the show came out, thanks to Obamacare. Walt's cancer would now be fully covered by his employment insurance - and later by COBRA, and eventually Medicaid if he's forced to quit his job. But the show came out in 2008, 4 years before Obamacare was passed.

Even pre-Obamacare wouldn't he have coverage as a public school teacher? The pay is generally poor but I assumed most states have a pension and decent health insurance for teachers.

OK, confirmed now in this excellent answer. IMO the comic gets it completely wrong and misunderstands how the US healthcare system actually worked, even back in 2008.

@JonathanReez To say his treatment would be covered by COBRA is kind of naive.  The way COBRA works is that you can continue your coverage for a limited period of time, but you're responsible for all the premiums, which can be thousands a month.  And usually COBRA kicks in when you're out of a job, since jobs and health insurance are so bound together in the US.  So COBRA lets you continue your coverage...if you can afford it despite having no job.

This comic is so stupid, it makes me think a redditor posted it.

Comic: "anywhere but America" would also need to exclude 3rd world countries in which wealth is very much a requirement to get just about anything.

He doesn't want to accept Elliot's offer because he thinks that is Elliot's pity, he is looking down on Walt and Walt's ego wants to be on top of everything. He doesn't want to be the employee, he wants to be the boss.

Say his name…

Just to add an important element to the other answers...

Given Walter's high intelligence and the obvious benefits of working at a successful pharmaceutical company, why didn't he make this seemingly more logical decision?

Walt's motivation wasn't to pay for his cancer - in fact he initially refused to get treated in the first place (see the pillow scene from Season 1). His actual motivation was to leave money for his family. Remember this dialogue from Season 2, Episode 1:

WALTER WHITE: Adjusting for inflation – good state college – adjusting for inflation. Say $45,000 a year, two kids, four years of college... $360,000
Remaining mortgage on the home, $107,000. Home equity line, $30,000, that's $137,000. Cost of living, food, clothing, utilities, say two grand a month?
I mean, that should put a dent in it, anyway. 24K a year provides for, say, ten years. That's $240,000, plus 360 plus 137... 737. $737,000, that's what I need. That is what I need.

Walt assumed that his cancer will quickly kill him (and wasn't wrong, he had roughly two somewhat healthy years left past his diagnosis) so he needed a lot of money to leave for his family. In 2008 a great salary for a chemist might be $150,000 after taxes. Deduct living expenses and Walt might be able to leave $200,000 to his family, which was clearly not enough.
Yes, there was absolutely an element of pride involved as explained in the other answers, but the job offer was also not enough to cover what Walt wanted for his family.

Gray Matter could have provided a high salary and potentially covered his medical expenses.

He already had insurance from his job as a school teacher that would've covered 'standard' medical treatment. The only reason he needed extra money for treatment was because Marie insisted on him going to the most expensive clinic in the state that wasn't covered by his plan, which he likewise resented:

Marie: Okay. So first thing tomorrow, I talk to my radiologists, we find you the best oncology dream team.
...
Skyler: Yeah, anytime on Friday is absolutely fine. Thank you so much for working us in. Can I just put that on a credit card? Great. Perfect. Okay, so we will see you at 10:45 on Friday morning. Thank you so much. The best oncologist I mean, not even just in New Mexico, but one of the top ten in the entire nation. His name is Dr. Delcavoli. And we see him on Friday. I mean, Marie really came through for us. She had her boss call and this is good. From here on out, things are gonna...
Walter: What's that we're putting on a credit card?
Skyler: It's just a deposit kind of thing.
Walter: How much of a deposit?
Skyler: It's $5,000.
Walter: Five thousand? And what's that? Just to start? Just to tell me
what I already know?
Skyler: Walt, he's not in our HMO, okay? So be it. We'll figure it
out. Come on. Don't get hung up on money here. We can always borrow
from Hank.
Walter: Absolutely not. No, I just, we're not gonna do that.


1 serious financial mistake Walter made was not buying insurance to cover for his death. Given his role as breadwinner, it was an unforgivable financial mistake.

@curious LOL... not becoming a drug lord, that was forgivable, but not doing proper financial planning was the unforgivable part.

Of course becoming a drug lord was unforgivable. If he had bought death insurance for himself, he might not have become a drug lord. Probably he might have become a high-level executive working at a billion-dollar company which he played a part in creating.

It's already quite some years that I watched the show. However I am quite certain Walter was already (deeply) involved in the drug trade when his old friends/business-partners offered him a job.
So there never was a choice of ENTERING the drug trade and taking a job at Gray Matter. The choice was between leaving the drug trade and taking a job at Gray Matter. By the time he got the offer from Gray Matter he was already quite accomplished in the drug trade and already had some blood on his hands, so there was no incentive to leave the drug trade.

Yes, he has blood on his hands already - Krazy 8 and Emilio which stems back to the first episode - but the offer from Grey Matter was only Episode 5 of the show. I would not say he was "accomplished".  He's only just gone to an Oncologist to find out about treatment for his cancer, this is only a few days into the story.
